# BeautifulSoup Iteration not working

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
s=requests.Session()
r=s.get('http://www.virginiaequestrian.com/main.cfm?action=greenpages&GPType=8')
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html5lib')

DataGrid=soup.find('tbody')
test=[]
for tr in DataGrid.find_all('tr')[:3]:
        for td in tr.find_all('td'):
            print td.string
```

Hi i'm trying to parse the html for this website(http://www.virginiaequestrian.com/main.cfm?action=greenpages&GPType=8) and to get the table data. I am trying to exclude the first three table rows from my results, but for some reason i can't get the parser to do this. This is my first professional scraping attempt and i am at a complete loss on how to get this working. I am guessing it might be something to do with the html5lib parser i am using, but honest i have no idea. Can somebody please tell me how i can get this working?

As a good test it would be very useful to pull data the first three rows.This way i could be confident the finished query will be pulling from anything but these.

For instance the first row in the table will be 'Equestrian Web Sites'

Comment: Add what you consider the first three rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are taking just the first three not ignoring `[:3]`, that slices the *first three elements* from the list:

```
 DataGrid.find_all('tr')[:3] # first three elements
```

Should be `DataGrid.find_all('tr')[3:]` # all but first three elements

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r=requests.get('http://www.virginiaequestrian.com/main.cfm?action=greenpages&GPType=8')
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content)

tbl = soup.find("table")
for tag in tbl.find_all("tr")[3:]:
    for td in tag.find_all('td'):
        print td.text
```

The above `tbl.find_all("tr")` when sliced and using two different parsers outputs:

```
In [20]: soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content,"html.parser")

In [21]: tbl = soup.find("table")

In [22]: len(tbl.find_all("tr"))
Out[22]: 364

In [23]: len(tbl.find_all("tr")[3:])
Out[23]: 361

In [24]: soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content,"lxml")

In [25]: tbl = soup.find("table")

In [26]: len(tbl.find_all("tr")[3:])
Out[26]: 361

In [27]: len(tbl.find_all("tr"))
Out[27]: 364
```

If you actually want the `more` hrefs then you should be doing exactly that, get the `a` tag for each `tr`, there are also 6 tr's before the row you actually want so you need to skip 6:

```
tbl = soup.find("table")
out = (tag.find('a') for tag in tbl.find_all("tr")[6:])

for a in out:
    print(a["href"])
```

Output:

```
main.cfm?action=greenpages&sub=view&ID=9068
main.cfm?action=greenpages&sub=view&ID=9504
main.cfm?action=greenpages&sub=view&ID=10868
main.cfm?action=greenpages&sub=view&ID=10261
main.cfm?action=greenpages&sub=view&ID=10477
main.cfm?action=greenpages&sub=view&ID=10708
main.cfm?action=greenpages&sub=view&ID=11712
main.cfm?action=greenpages&sub=view&ID=12402
main.cfm?action=greenpages&sub=view&ID=12496
..................
```

To use the links just prepend the main url:

```
for a in out:
    print("http://www.virginiaequestrian.com/{}".format(a["href"]))
```

Output:

```
http://www.virginiaequestrian.com/main.cfm?action=greenpages&sub=view&ID=9068
http://www.virginiaequestrian.com/main.cfm?action=greenpages&sub=view&ID=9504
http://www.virginiaequestrian.com/main.cfm?action=greenpages&sub=view&ID=10868
http://www.virginiaequestrian.com/main.cfm?action=greenpages&sub=view&ID=10261
http://www.virginiaequestrian.com/main.cfm?action=greenpages&sub=view&ID=10477
http://www.virginiaequestrian.com/main.cfm?action=greenpages&sub=view&ID=10708
http://www.virginiaequestrian.com/main.cfm?action=greenpages&sub=view&ID=11712
http://www.virginiaequestrian.com/main.cfm?action=greenpages&sub=view&ID=12402
http://www.virginiaequestrian.com/main.cfm?action=greenpages&sub=view&ID=12496
http://www.virginiaequestrian.com/main.cfm?action=greenpages&sub=view&ID=12633
http://www.virginiaequestrian.com/main.cfm?action=greenpages&sub=view&ID=13528
```

Which if you open the first will lead you to *Equestrian Web Sites*, i.e the first data you want.

Comment: Yeah i did that because there were a lot of elements in the table and i wanted to test if the slice was working. I changed the numbers around a bunch and i didn't see it as having any effect. I always got back the full list....

Comment: It works for me, try changing your parser, are you sure printing `DataGrid.find_all('tr')[:3]` and `DataGrid.find_all('tr')` give you exactly the same output?

Comment: if i use the default or 'lxml' i get a NoneType Error. Which is why i have to use html5lib. I printed DataGrid=soup.find('tbody')
test=[]
for tr in DataGrid.find_all('tr'):
  for td in tr.find_all('td'):
   print td.text
   test.append(td)

print '\n%i' % len(test) and including  [:3] i get a count of 3601. If i don't include a slicer i get a count of 5399...which actually now brings up the question of why with a 364 element table, do the first 3 elements compose over half the count.....

Comment: run the code exactly  as above and add the length of `tbl.find_all("tr")[3:]` and `tbl.find_all("tr")`

Comment: I'm using whatever one is in the most recent version of anaconda....I know three parsing options, lxml, the default, and html5lib. The first two didn't work, so i think i'm stuck with  html5lib

Comment: What does, `import bs4;bs4.__version__` output? Also what OS?

Comment: My OS is OSX, and it looks like the version is 4.3.2

Comment: Have you run the code in my answer and gotten the length?

Comment: data=[]
for tag in tbl.find_all("tr")[3:]:
    for td in tag.find_all('td'):
        print td.text
        data.append(td)

print len(data)        
returns 1798... I am still working on getting length for tbl.find_all('tr'). I don't know how to quickly get the length for that

Comment: Both lxml and html.parser fail for me using your code using tbody, using table both work fine. Use `DataGrid=soup.find('table');print sum(1 for tr in DataGrid.find_all('tr')[:3] for td in tr.find_all('td'))` with lxml and html.parser, then tell me the sum

Comment: Yeah lxml is working with table for me as well..... I keep trying to return the first 3 rows in the table, and I keep getting all of them when i try to slice [:3

Comment: ok let try,  can you also add exactly what you want to extract to your question

Comment: Regarding the sum, running that script for me returns 3601. I want to extract everything except the first three rows, but as I am troubleshooting i am trying to test whether or not it is working by first slicing the stuff out that i don't want to extract.

Comment: same for me so we get the same output, do you want the rows from  `Equestrian Web Sites` to `Farm & Ranch Designs - Custom Breeder Websites`?

Comment: As test yes that could be helpful. But primarily it only helps for me to make sure i'm not including junk for the first couple of rows

Comment: Just add exactly  what you want to your question, the first row  in the tables td.text is `Services & Products (358 listings)` so are you trying to skip that?

Comment: Ok just did that. Question is fully updated. I hope that helps.

Comment: The end goal is to grab the links in 4th column for each row(more column) that's why i want to iterate by row. out = (td.text for tr in DataGrid.find_all('tr') for td in tr.find_all('td')[11:]) gets me the table data i think, but i lose the ability to select efficiently by value...I'm sorry if i didn't say that clearly.

Comment: what value are you referring to? `tbl = soup.find("table");out = (tag.find_all('td') for tag in tbl.find_all("tr")[6:])` will get all the rows td tags, you can extract whatever you want from them, there are more than 3 tr tags before the first actual data in the table that is why you were not getting what you wanted

Comment: How many rows do i need to ignore. I'm still counting three in the source code?? BTW thank you for the help i appreciate it.

Comment: No worries, if I knew you just wanted the more links life would have been simpler! I added the code to get them